# Point Intersection With Polygon in Ruby

Tags: ruby, tree, indexing, r-tree

**How can I quickly find which of a set of polygons contain a given point?**

I have a collection of polygons in a [POSTGis](http://postgis.net/) database.  I'm using [RGeo](https://github.com/dazuma/rgeo) on the ruby side to manipulate, save, and pull information from/to the database.

I receive a point (x and y coordinates) from an external machine and need to know which of my polygons this point lies within.  I can't use the database because I need this to be done in memory for performance reasons.

I believe I might need an [r-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree), but I don't exactly want to write one.

`RGeo` provides a `contains?` method that I can use to ensure a point is within a polygon of interest, but I need to know which polygon to check.  I have on the order of 1,000 polygons and doing a linear search is not time efficient enough for my needs.

Comment: The community has decided that questions asking for software or library recommendations are off-topic for SO.  [This post on meta explains some of the reasons why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/141929)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll look into it to see if I can change up the question.

Comment: I've tried updating the question to fit within SO's guidelines.

Comment: That's a whole lot better.  I think it can be improved some more.  I'll take a stab at it, if you don't mind--if my edit isn't good, please roll it back.

Comment: Another question saved from purgatory.  Thank you for your positive response to the closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can [this](http://ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/neartree-0.2/NearTree/RTree.html) help? otherwise, there is [this](https://github.com/susano/ruby-neartree).

It seems that neartree is a better thing to search for w.r.t. ruby.

Hope this helps!

EDIT: if you need a general purpose implementation of an rtree, maybe the boost (c++) library can help there are bindings for it [here](http://www.ssalewski.de/RT.html.de).
that has bindings for methods which should help your use-case:

```
intersects?
intersects_each?
intersects_rect?
intersects_rect_each?
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I wasn't clear in my question.  I need something to find intersections, so I don't think a nearest data structure will be helpful.  Thanks for the links though.  BTW, what is w.r.t.?

Comment: afaik, wrt is acronyme for "with respect to"

Comment: @MikeH-R - You know how I might include this in a rails app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101444/how-to-include-c-bindings-in-a-rails-project

Comment: @TylerDeWitt sorry, that's where my knowledge ends. Good luck :)