# How to include c++ bindings in a rails project

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, wrapper

I asked this [question about r-trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078290/ruby-rtree-implementation) and the answer included using a c++ library with some ruby wrappers.  I've gotten the wrapper to work in a test file, but how can I include the wrapper in my rails project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I included the folder containing the files (`RTREE` in this case) in the `/lib` folder of my project. I then ran `ruby exconf.rb` from within that folder.  Lastly, I included the necessary file in my project (`require RBOOST/rboost_rtree_2d_rect`).  With that, I was good to go.